# How do I set up a Stanford CoreNLP Server on Windows to return sentiment for text

Tags: java, server, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am attempting to set up a local server on Windows with Stanford CoreNLP to calculate sentiment scores for over 1M article and video texts. I don't know Java, so I will need some help.

I successfully installed Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0, and I have a server running with:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

Running this http post from my other computer works, and I get an expected response (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server's IP address):

```
wget --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

However, the response doesn't contain sentiment. The obvious solution would be to add an annotator:

```
wget --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

However, on the server side, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown annotator: sentiment
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.ensurePrerequisiteAnnotators(StanfordCoreNLP.java:281)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.getProperties(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:476)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:350)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The next obvious solution would be to add a parameter to starting the server, which runs:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment"
```

Running the same http posts from before gives the same exact result and error, respectively.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some modification to the core code that it needs to work? I don't know Java, so I am unable to make those changes.

As a side note, this similar command starts a console, and seems to load sentiment correctly:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment"

[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.5 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.4 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator sentiment

Entering interactive shell. Type q RETURN or EOF to quit.
NLP> _
```

Comment: That sentiment analyzer is not good enough though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running with the [GitHub version](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) of the code. Your first solution is correct -- the fact that it could not find the sentiment annotator is a bug in the code:

```
wget --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/?properties={"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

(A side note: the `tokenize.whitespace` property is in the documentation to show that you can pass in arbitrary properties, but I recommend against using it in production).

Comment: Downloading the GitHub version isn't very helpful, since there is no documentation for how to use it. They just point to the documentation for the download on their website, which is set up differently. I have not been successful with it yet.

Comment: Just run `ant jar` and it should make a jar file that you can use in place of the official release.

Comment: This worked for me. (Running `ant` first and then `ant jar`.) Note that the github version doesn't have all the models, so you might have to download them [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar). Also, I'm not very familiar with java, so I had trouble figuring out the command to run to include the jar file that ant made and the model jar and the jars in `lib`. In case others have issues, here's what worked for me: `java -mx4g -cp "javanlp-core.jar:stanford-english-corenlmodels-current.jar:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer`